# "С Нового года" или "с нового года"?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Предложение было такое: "Я с нового года начинаю работать в другом месте". С одной стороны, речь идет о будущем годе, который сменит тот, что идет сейчас. Но, с другой стороны, "Новый год", вроде как, пишется с большой буквы, но это название праздника, поэтому логичнее было бы писать со строчной буквы, потому что речь тут не о празднике, а о смене года.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее написать "новый год" в данном контексте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку  оба значения сводятся к 1 января нового года - это и праздник, и начало года, - оба варианта будут корректны, как подскажет интуиция. Если Вы имеете в виду праздник - с прописной, большой, если обычный год - со строчной, маленькой.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше использовать строчную букву: начинаю работать с нового года.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

"Начинаю работать с праздника" звучит не лучшим образом.

Comment: Прописная и есть большая, её "прописывают", вырисовывают. Маленькая - строчная.

Comment: Текст исправлен

Answer (score 0):

Согласен. Лучше со строчной. Здесь имеется в виду начало нового года. Как верно отметила София:"Начинаю работать с праздника" звучит не лучшим образом.>>.

Comment: Есть нюанс. Начинают работать обычно после праздничных дней - с 10-11 января, но бывают компании, которые принимают новых работников и в праздник, вот они начинают работать с Нового года, с самого праздника.Так что возможны оба варианта, а уж что лучше, что хуже - пусть разбирается автор.

Comment: В  этом  случае  лучше  сказать - с  1  января.

Comment: Конечно, со строчной. С нового года = с началом нового года = в новом году. Мы же не напишем "С 8 Марта я иду в отпуск".

Comment: @Людмила Автор уже разобрался: "речь тут не о празднике, а о смене года" (из текста вопроса).